# gulp dependent tasks - browserify and a pre-browserify task

Tags: javascript, ember.js, gulp, browserify

I have the following [gulpfile](https://gist.github.com/knownasilya/648428c8685ab59fb3dd)

And I'm using [emberate](https://www.npmjs.org/package/emberate), which takes a callback which is called when the generated file (`client/.index.js` in this case) has been written. Now the `browserify` task depends on that file, so it shouldn't run till after emberate finishes. But I get different results, sometimes it works and other times I get this:

> Error: Cannot find module './client/.index.js' from '/Users/myuser/workspace/myproject'

from browserify (and yes, the file is not there yet)..  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I have `done` as the callback in my emberate task, and browserify task depends on emberate.. What am I missing?

**Edit**: found a small pattern, if I run it and it doesn't error, the next time I run `gulp` i get the error, but the next time I don't, so it's every other time o.O

If I run `gulp emberate`, that works great. Then if I run `gulp browserify` it runs the following:

```
[gulp] Using file /Users/myuser/workspace/myproject/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Working directory changed to /Users/myuser/workspace/myproject
[gulp] Running 'clean'...
[gulp] Finished 'clean' in 3.11 ms
[gulp] Running 'emberate'...
[gulp] Finished 'emberate' in 22 ms
[gulp] Running 'browserify'...
[gulp] Live reload server listening on: 35729

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Cannot find module './client/.index.js' from '/Users/myuser/workspace/myproject'
    at /Users/myuser/workspace/myproject/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:36:25
    at load (/Users/myuser/workspace/myproject/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:54:43)
    at /Users/myuser/workspace/myproject/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:60:22
    at /Users/myuser/workspace/myproject/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:16:47
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

This latest [version](https://gist.github.com/knownasilya/648428c8685ab59fb3dd) seems to work, but during a watch if files were changed, it doesn't clean up the `client/.index.js` file, but keeps adding to it o.O (although running `gulp emberate` with or without the `clean` dependency works just fine..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was a bug in `emberate`, concerning templates when using one process, which `gulp.watch` was doing.

This is my final `gulpfile.js`:

```
  var path = require('path');
  var gulp = require('gulp');
  var less = require('gulp-less');
  var refresh = require('gulp-livereload');
  var clean = require('gulp-clean');
  var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
  var emberate = require('emberate');
  var browserify = require('browserify');

  gulp.task('less', function () {
    return gulp.src('./client/styles/*.less')
      .pipe(less({
        paths: [
          path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'styles')
        ]
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/styles'))
      .pipe(refresh());
  });

  gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src('./client/.index.js', { read: false })
      .pipe(clean());
  });

  gulp.task('emberate', ['clean'], function () {
    return emberate('./client', { pods: true })
      .pipe(source('.index.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./client'));
  });

  gulp.task('browserify', ['emberate'], function () {
    return browserify('./client/.index.js')
      .bundle()
      //Pass desired output filename to vinyl-source-stream
      .pipe(source('application.js'))
      // Start piping stream to tasks!
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/scripts/'))
      .pipe(refresh());
  });

  gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./client/styles/*.less', ['less']);
    gulp.watch('./client/**/*.{js,hbs}', ['browserify']);
  });

 gulp.task('default', ['less', 'browserify', 'watch']);
```

Which works great :)

Comment: There was also an issue with `gulp-clean`, which did not handle the async part correctly, so my coworker submitted a PR here: https://github.com/peter-vilja/gulp-clean/pull/9

Answer (score 2):

You need to give gulp hints about how each task will complete.  See https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support

In all of your tasks switch this:

```
gulp.task('name', function () {
  gulp.src(glob)
    .pipe(stuff());
});
```

to this:

```
gulp.task('name', function () {
  return gulp.src(glob)
    .pipe(stuff());
});
```

Note that your `less` task and your `emberate` don't currently do this

Comment: Actually `emberate` uses the callback method (`done`) and the `less` task is async and not dependent on anything, so I don't think it's the culprit. I tried adding the return to emberate as well, but same results (doesn't delete the file, just adds to it on watch).

Comment: You're right, `emberate` uses the callback.  `less` will benefit from the return though.  It sounds like both the `emberate` and `browserify` tasks are behaving badly though: if the process is really to take the out file from one and into the other, they shouldn't pull them from the filesystem, but rather you should `return gulp.src('stuff for enberate').pipe(emberate()).pipe(browserify()).pipe(gulp.dest('location'))` within one task.

Comment: Thanks for your help @robrich, I figured out the issue, see my answer.

Comment: I'm so confused on the documentation - it says "Tasks can be made asynchronous if its fn does one of the following..." - don't they mean *synchronous*?